# VBA loop until two numbers add up to a certain number

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am new to Visual Basic and I would like to ask how to do a loop until two numbers add up to 100. Basically, I want the user to keep entering the two numbers (via inputbox) until those two numbers add up to 100.
The current codes I have is as follow but it keeps **crashing**:

```
Public Sub Task2_B()
Do Until TotalWeight = 100
      Do Until Val(weightA) = Int(Val(weightA)) And IsNumeric(weightA) And weightA <> "" And weightA > 0 
                  weightA = Application.InputBox("Please enter weightA:", "Enter a positive integer", 100)
                  If weightA = False Then Exit Sub
      Loop

      Do Until Val(weightB) = Int(Val(weightB)) And IsNumeric(weightB) And weightB <> "" And weightB > 0
                  weightB = Application.InputBox("Please enter weightB:", "Enter a positive integer", 100)
                  If weightB = False Then Exit Sub
      Loop
      TotalWeight = Int(weightA) + Int(weightB)
Loop
Debug.Print TotalWeight
End Sub
```

Comment: Where does it crash and what is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your logic is redundant and repeated. Let's first define what valid input is once:

```
Public Function InputIsValid(ByVal theInput As String) As Boolean
    InputIsValid = (Val(theInput) = Int(Val(theInput))) And Val(theInput) > 0
End Function
```

The first condition verifies that the input is a whole number. The second states it must be greater than zero. We know that it is numeric and not an empty string at this point so we don't need those additional tests.

Now we use that to validate our input:

```
Public Sub Task2B()
    Dim TotalWeight As Long
    Do Until TotalWeight = 100
        Dim weightA As Variant
        Do
            weightA = InputBox("Please enter weightA:", "Enter a positive integer", 100)
            If weightA = False Then Exit Sub
        Loop Until InputIsValid(weightA)
        
        Dim weightB As Variant
        Do
            weightB = InputBox("Please enter weightB:", "Enter a positive integer", 100)
            If weightB = False Then Exit Sub
        Loop Until InputIsValid(weightB)
        
        TotalWeight = Val(weightA) + Val(weightB)
        Debug.Print TotalWeight
    Loop
End Sub
```

Notice I declared all the variables in use. I am also checking the state of the input bottom of the loop because it hasn't been set yet at the top.

Finally, we use `Val` to cast our string to a numeric every time we use it.

Comment: Nicely done. 2 minor suggestions, if I may. **1.** Use [Application.InputBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) with `Type:=1`. That will take care of the `VAL()` part. You can directly do the comparision. `If weightA > 0` **2.** Declare the variables as `Variant` instead of `String`

Comment: Thank you so much! The second part works but for some reasons, the function does not work (inputs are not validated(type mismatch error if I type a letter)), is there anything I need to do when working with a function?

Comment: The function would only work if I do not dim weightA or weightB as string but it is all working. Thank you so much, HackSlash.

Comment: @canislupus, you're right it needs to be `Variant` because you later use it like a `Boolean`. You should be putting `Option Explicit` at the top of every module. This forces you to declare all of your variables. This is important because it can save you from typo errors. It also forces you to be specific about variables types in a land where VBA plays fast and loose with types.

Comment: @HackSlash, thanks for the tip! will definitely add it to my codes from now on.